# When an automatic variable get out of scope, in what order operations occurs?

Tags: c++, scope, language-lawyer, c++98

I'm building a simple `{ mutex, value }` pair as follows, and I'd like to check with c++ lawyers if my use case is well defined.

#### Tool definition

```
template<typename T, class mutex> class Locker;

template<typename T, class mutex>
class Mutexed
{
    T     _value;
    mutex _mutex;
    friend class Locker<T, mutex>;
public:
    Mutexed() {}
    Mutexed(const T& init)           : _value(init) {}
    Mutexed(const Mutexed<T>& other) : _value(other._value) {}
};

template<typename T, class mutex>
class Locker
{
    Mutexed<T, mutex>& _mutexed;
public:
    Locker(Mutexed<T, mutex>& mutexed) : _mutexed(mutexed) { _mutexed.mutex.lock(); }
    ~Locker() { _mutexed.mutex.unlock(); }
    const T& operator*() const { return _mutexed.value; }
          T& operator*()       { return _mutexed.value; }
};
```

#### Use case

```
Mutexed<int, MyMutex> answer(42);
int getAnswer() { Locker<int> lock(answer); return *lock; }
```

#### My concern

Since `*lock`, *id est* `const T& operator*() const { return _mutexed.value; }` returns a reference to `answer._value`, a copy from `int&` to `int` is made. But since, `lock` goes out of scope while returning: **which of the copy and the mutex unclock will happen first**?

#### tl;dr

Is my usecase not UB xor do I need to write?

```
const int result = *lock;
return result;
```

Comment: @NathanOlivier Thank you for the duplicate. it's a nice find!

Comment: Note that if destructor happened before the copy, you'd never be able to return a local object from a function.

Comment: @Barry Stated like that, it sounds so obvious: it should be an (accepted) answer.